# How to execute a very long command line when launching a java program?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, java

I need to start a java application with lot of additional libraries (libraries can be linked in runtime using `-cp` argument). When I paste this command line in command prompt, it says the command line is too long and does not start anything. Any attempts to use batch file and variables have failed too. How can I correctly execute a statement that has over 3600 characters in length?

Comment: For  Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is [8191 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473)

Answer (score 0):

Move the java app so the route to execute the file is shorter,e.g c:\java instead of C:\Users\Computer\Documents\Mycode\java. secondly shorten the file name as well,using these steps you can reduce the number of characters you use, although this wont work if you are many characters over the limit